# Service Registery with many unreliable services, located everywhere on the internet

Tags: java, architecture, apache-zookeeper

For a project me and my friends are building, I've been looking into service discovery. But I failed to find a suitable solution to the specific problem.

We developed a service which is clustered on multiple servers. I'll call this service the master-service from now on. This service knows several API definitions. Pretty basic until this point.

Now we have around 30 services. Each service has a unique ID, implements one or more API definitions and is deployed on one or more servers. Each of those servers may host a specific selection of API definitions.

Those servers can be located everywhere and will be very unreliable. This means that each server can shutdown at any moment and may have a very unreliable internet connection.

The amount of services may grow at any time, since everyone will be able to implement one of those API definitions.

The master-service must be able to locate a specific service by its unique ID and call a specific API definition. This can fail when a service isn't available or the requested API definition isn't registered. The calls will be basic HTTP requests.

This means that each service / server combination must register itself at the master service. This registration must be updated near instant when a service / server disconnects.

The master-server is implemented in Java and the services may be implemented in any programming language.

What are good technologies / techniques to handle these kind of requirements?

Is Apache ZooKeeper suitable for these kinds of requirements?